# square root in Sympy differential euqation

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am working on initial value problems of differential equations.

When I try

```
t = sym.symbols('t')
y = sym.Function('y')
eq3c = sym.Eq(y(t).diff(t), t-2*math.sqrt(y(t)))
print("The equation")
display_latex(eq3c)
eq3c_sol = sym.dsolve(eq3c, y(t), ics={y(0):1})
```

I got error message (regarding math.sqrt())

```
TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

And, if I try

```
t = sym.symbols('t')
y = sym.Function('y')
eq3c = sym.Eq(y(t).diff(t), t-2*(y(t))**(1/2))
print("The equation")
display_latex(eq3c)
eq3c_sol = sym.dsolve(eq3c, y(t), ics={y(0):1})
```

I got error message

```
NotImplementedError: The given ODE -1.0*t + 2.0*sqrt(y(t)) + Derivative(y(t), t) cannot be solved by the factorable group method
```

Can someone point out why my square root is not working??

Comment: `math.sqrt` is only for floats, numbers, not `sympy` symbols (or expressions).

Comment: So, should I convert sympy into numpy using ```sym.lambdify(y(t),eq3c , 'numpy')``` ?

Comment: If you're looking for a symbolic solution use `sym.sqrt`.

Comment: If I use ```sym.sqrt``` when I try to solve the initial condition y(0)=1 (shown above) I run into the error ```NotImplementedError: The given ODE -t + 2*sqrt(y(t)) + Derivative(y(t), t) cannot be solved by the lie group method```